# Undefined method `card_number' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a credit card form by using Stripe API. I should not migrate db for card form, so I have to just send credit card information to Stripe directly.

I use `gem 'gon'` and some JS files.
This is reference to develop this.
https://medium.com/@ThatGuyTinus/stripe-connect-rails-part-2-9751c0e553f9

Error occurs:

> undefined method `card_number' for

Views(views/users/payment.html.erb):

```
<%= include_gon %>
<section class="registerCommunity">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Set up credit card</h2>
    <%= form_for(@user, html: {class:'add-card'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="block">
        <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_temporary_token %>
        <div class="formItem">
          <%= f.label :card_number %>
          <div class="formInput"><%= f.text_field :card_number, placeholder: "Enter card number", data: {stripe: 'number'} %></div>
        </div>
        ・・・
```

Controllers(controllers/application_controller.erb):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :assign_env_variable

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end

  def assign_env_variable
    gon.stripe_key = ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']
  end
end
```

Views(views/layouts/application.html.erb):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script> 

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve by removing `f.`.

Before:

```
    <div class="formItem">
      <%= f.label :card_number %>
      <div class="formInput"><%= f.text_field :card_number, placeholder: "Enter card number", data: {stripe: 'number'} %></div>
    </div>
```

After:

```
    <div class="formItem">
      <%= f.label :card_number %>
      <div class="formInput"><%= text_field :card_number, placeholder: "Enter card number", data: {stripe: 'number'} %></div>
    </div>
```